# Cannot edit my own question because of validation

Tags: support, edits, editing-help

I would like to correct this question [Can I change the scroll speed using css or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408100/can-i-change-the-scroll-speed-using-css-or-jquery)

Changing the end of the first paragraph from this:

```
as one one wheel scrolls approxilately the div's height.
```

To this:

```
as one wheel tick scrolls approximately the div's height.
```

(correcting my own typos)

Unfortunately, I cannot do that because of the following validation error:

```
Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all 
code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard 
shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
```

Including a code snippet here does not make sense, since I'm using jsfiddle as an example where I have a UI element (a div with small height) about which I'd like to change the scroll speed. The jsfiddle is not an attempt at doing that, just an example of such a div.

How can I fix my own typo here?

Comment: Take the code out of the fiddle and put it in the question as a stack snippet?

Comment: Why do you think that showing an example of the problem you're having *doesn't* belong in the question itself?

Comment: cross site dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197404/editing-a-question-with-only-a-jsfiddle-link-does-not-work

Comment: It's old doesn't mean that it doesn't need to follow new rules.

Answer (score 6):

As @JonClements suggested, I ended up using the stack snippet feature.